# problem in counting children category

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:

```
fourn_category (id , sub)
```

I am using this code to count:

```
function CountSub($id){
$root = array($id);
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM fourn_category WHERE sub = '$id'");                                            

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){

        array_push($root,$row['id']);
       CountSub($row['id']);
    }        

    return implode(",",$root);  
}
```

It returns the category id as 1,2,3,4,5 to using it to count the sub by `IN()`

But the problem is that it counts this:

**category 1** > category 2 > category 3 > category 4 > category 5

Category 1 has 1 child not 4.
Why? How can I get all children's trees?

Comment: We will need sample data to see why category 1 has one child and not 4.  Is your table representing tree-structured data?  Are you trying to count the number of connected sub-nodes for each node listed?  Do you need zeroes for nodes only listed in the 'sub' column?  If I'm on the right track, then you need to look up Celko's book on [Trees and Hierarchies](http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Kaufmann-Management-Systems/dp/1558609202).

Comment: @moustafa，mind your manners man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, I suspect that you have a scope issue in your code. Try :

```
function CountSub($id, &$current=array()){
    array_push($current, $id);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM fourn_category WHERE sub = '$id'");                                            

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){
        CountSub($row['id'], $current);
    }        

    return implode(",",$current);  
}

CountSub(1)
```

In your code, a new *$root* array is created at each level of the recursive function and the recursive calls never modify the original created array, which may be your problem

I Hope this will help
Jerome

Comment: great idea i will try and tell you

Comment: what & mean in &$current=array()

Comment: the & means that you are passing the array as a reference and not as a value. Passing the variable by value would make a copy of the array, which would be modified inside the function but not available from the calling function. Passing the variable by reference makes sure that you handle the same array at each level of your recursive function.